# is it ok to specialize std::numeric_limits<T> for user-defined number-like classes?

Tags: c++, types, numbers, standards

The documentation of `std::numeric_limits<T>` says it should not be specialized for non-fundamental types.  What about number-like user-defined types?  If I define my own type `T` which represents a numeric value and overloads numeric operators, and for which the information represented by `numeric_limits` makes sense -- will anything break if I specialize `numeric_limits` for that type?

Comment: By definition any user-defined type (UDT) is *not* a fundamental type.

Comment: It says "non-fundamental standard types" shall not have specializations. So for non-standard types it would be ok (when it makes sense).

Answer (score 38):

### Short answer:

Go ahead, nothing bad will happen.

### Long answer:

The C++ standard extensively protects the `::std` namespace in C++11 17.6.4.2.1, but specifically allows your case in paragraphs 1 and 2:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
>   namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization
>   for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
>   and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
>   prohibited.
>
> [...] A program may explicitly instantiate a template defined in the standard library only if the declaration
>   depends on the name of a user-defined type and the instantiation meets the standard library requirements
>   for the original template.

The older C++03 has a similar definition in 17.4.3.1/1:

> It is undefined for a C++ program to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or namespaces
>   within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add template specializations for any
>   standard library template to namespace std. Such a specialization (complete or partial) of a standard
>   library template results in undefined behavior unless the declaration depends on a user-defined name of
>   external linkage and unless the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

After getting past this fundamental stepping stone, you already pointed out, C++03 18.2.1/4 forbids specializations of `::std::numeric_limits` for certain types:

> Non-fundamental standard types, such as complex (26.2.2), shall not have specializations.

The more current C++11 18.3.2.1/4 has a slightly different wording:

> Non-arithmetic standard types, such as `complex<T>` (26.4.2), shall not have specializations.

Both of these formulations however allow specializations for non-standard types, which `T` is, since you defined it yourself (as @BoPersson already pointed out in the comments).

#### Caveats

C++11 18.3.2.3/1 hints that you should (but does not require you to) ensure that your specialization has all members.

Also, you may wish to ensure that C++11 18.3.2.3/2 is not violated by your specialization:

> The value of each member of a specialization of numeric_limits on a cv-qualified type cv T shall be equal
>   to the value of the corresponding member of the specialization on the unqualified type T.

Which essentially means, that if you wish to specialize it for `T`, you should also do so for `T const`, `T volatile` and `T const volatile`.

Comment: To me, this reads like a contradiction to 17.6.4.2.1/2: *"The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares an explicit specialization of any member function of a standard library class template"*. What am I missing?

Comment: This is not about explicitly specializing a **member function**, but the whole class template.

Comment: "Such a specialization [...] results in undefined behavior unless [...] the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template." The original requirements only apply to arithmetic types, suggesting that user specializations may have undefined behavior.

Comment: @RichardSmith If you can substantiate the fact that the original requirements have an implicit "must be an arithmetic type" somewhere, I might be inclined to believe you. However, as far as I remember (the last edit to this question was may '13), nothing in the standards mandates this.

Comment: Please explain why one of the many template argument resolution mechanisms wouldn't use a specialization of `std::numeric_limits<T>` for instantiations using cv-qualified T.

Comment: @Spencer Because e.g. `int const` and `int` are two different types, which [will cause the default to be chosen](http://ideone.com/pJsvpr). There are basically no additional resolution mechanisms when passing a template type parameter directly (unlike what happens when passing an ordinary argument to a function template w/o explicitly specifying the template parameters).

Answer (score 28):

Just an example:

```
namespace std {
    template<> class numeric_limits<Temperature> {
    public:
       static Temperature lowest() {return Temperature(-273.15f);};
       // One can implement other methods if needed
    };
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Could you elaborate how to extend this solution for templated templated classes?  E.g., if I have `template <typename T> struct WrapperAroundT { T m_data; };` and I really want `numeric_limit<WrapperAroundT>` to apply on the underlying T

Comment: You really want this to be a `constexpr` function

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps

I believe you can just

`template<typename T> class ::std::numeric_limits< WrapperAroundT< T > > : public ::std::numeric_limits<T> { };` and that should do it