# C++: Overloaded template alias

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Currently programming a specialized Standard Library, and I find that in a particular case this is necessary for me:

```
namespace std
{
  // key, value
  template<class K, class V>
  using vector_map = other_namespace::vector_map<K, V>;

  // key, value, compare
  template<class K, class V, class C>
  using vector_map = other_namespace::vector_map<K, V, C>;
}
```

It does, however, not work. Not surprising. But what are my options to achieving this?
I have thought about using the precprocessor, but I want to know what you guys think.

I want to be able to selective alias template class into another namespace, if possible.

Solution (in my case) was to add a default value instead of having several usings:

```
namespace std
{
  // key, value, compare
  template<class K, class V, class C = default_value>
  using vector_map = other_namespace::vector_map<K, V, C>;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `other_namespace::vector_map` isn't "overloaded" either, it just has a default for `C`. Could that work for you too?

Comment: I want to have the same functionality as if the template class itself was in the same namespace that my using statement is in. In this example vector_map is in other_namespace, but I want to move specific variants over to std:: namespace: <K, V> and <K, V, C> types.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I just added the default value to my template alias, and that solves it. Thanks again

Comment: I don't get why you put this declaration into `namespace std`? You're about to produce "undefined behavior", see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122912/is-it-ok-to-specialize-stdnumeric-limitst-for-user-defined-number-like-class) for example.

Comment: I know, and I'm still thinking about all of this. This is for an operating system without a timer interrupt, so there can be no (complete) standard library anyways. I am currently using `std` only because it's going to be familiar to users. Ultimately it's not my decision though.

Comment: There is no `vector_map` in `std`, so why would having it in `std` make your users feel familiar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to write a fancy conditional forwarder, you'll have to not just use `using`.

```
template<class A, class B, class... C>
struct vector_map_helper {
  using type = other_namespace::vector_map<A,B>;
};
// specialize for 3:
template<class A, class B, class C>
struct vector_map_helper<A,B,C> {
  using type = other_namespace::vector_map<A,B,C>;
};
template<class A, class B, class C, class D, class...Z>
struct vector_map_helper<A,B,C,D, Z...>; // error 4 or more

template<class A, class B, class... C>
using vector_map = typename vector_map_helper<A,B,C...>::type;
```

in general, even if you are implementing a `std` library, you should avoid adding any "user facing" interfaces to your `std` that do not come from the `std` library.  And the stuff you do support should match `std` specifications.

Have a `nonstd` or a `std_ext` namespace for non-`std` extensions.  This will both make existing code either fail to compile or work when ported over, and it will avoid training your programmer-users in bad habits about what is in `std`.

It is also illegal to add most things to `std` with narrow exceptions, like `std::hash` specializations.