# Using std::map with Eigen 3

Tags: c++, eigen3

For efficiency purposes I need to write a code that takes a vector of integers as defined in Eigen 3, VectorXi, and maps that vector to a character. Like a dictionary in Python. How can I do this? The Eigen documentation does things the other way around (see below) - it maps a character to a vector. I can't get it to work in reverse. Has anyone ever tried this before?

```
std::map<char,VectorXi, std::less<char>,
     Eigen::aligned_allocator<std::pair<char, VectorXi> > > poop;

VectorXi check(modes);
check << 0,2,0,0;
poop['a']=check;
cout << poop['a'];
```

Comment: For starters, you probably want to use an unordered_map, unless you want to define a sort function for VectorXi.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is trying to approach the solution from the completely opposite side. There, you construct a map in which the keys are of type `char` and the values are Eigen vectors.

Note further that according to the [Eigen homepage](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStlContainers.html) custom allocators are only required for the *fixed-size* versions of Eigen types.

In order to use a `std::map` with a Eigen vector as key, you need an appropriate comparison function. For this, you can specialize `std::less` which is [allowed for custom types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122912/is-it-ok-to-specialize-stdnumeric-limitst-for-user-defined-number-like-class). Here is a possible implementation:

```
namespace std
{
     template<>
     std::less<Eigen::VectorXi>(Eigen::VectorXi const& a, Eigen::VectorXi const& b)
     {
          assert(a.size()==b.size());
          for(size_t i=0;i<a.size();++i)
          {
               if(a[i]<b[i]) return true;
               if(a[i]>b[i]) return false;
          }
          return false;
     }
}
```

Then you should be able to write

```
std::map<VectorXi, char> poop;

VectorXi check;
check << 0,2,0,0;
poop[check]='a';
cout << poop[check];  //prints 'a'
```

The code above is untested, however.

Comment: Alright! This is exactly what I was looking for. My vectors are ordered lexicographically, so the inequalities will have to defined a little bit differently, but I got it from here. Thanks bra.

Comment: Fine. But what I've written is lexicographic ordering imo.