# Is there a way to define traits and cast operators for redefined, via `typedef`, basic types?

Tags: c++, casting, operators, typedef

I've written a pair of converter functions for conversions between the floating point representation of angles in radians and the binary angles (aka [BAMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_scaling#Binary_angles)):

```
// Binary angles that maps into 360 degree circle
typedef uint8_t  binang8_t;
typedef uint16_t binang16_t;
typedef uint32_t binang32_t;
typedef uint64_t binang64_t;

// Convert from radians to BAMS
template<typename A, typename T> A to_binang(T val);

// Convert from radians or BAMS
template<typename T, typename A> T to_rads(A val);
```

The main issue is my `is_binangle`trait I created for use inside the converters does not protect against use of unsigned integers in place of new types. ***I know, I can define those new types as structures and it will solve this problem*** , but I have reason not to declare them as `class` or `struct`(to avoid redefining arithmetic operators and to stay compatible with old C payload headers). Is there a trick to get it working with types defined using `typedef`?
Here is my attempt at implementing that trait :

```
template<typename T> struct is_binangle {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<> struct is_binangle<binang8_t> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

template<> struct is_binangle<binang16_t> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

...
```

Ideally I'd prefer to define custom casts for those types, so that one can convert by just:

```
double rangle = M_PI/6;
binang16_t bang =  binang16_t(rangle);
bang += bang;
double another_rangle = double(another_bang);
```

I have strong suspicion that it is impossible unless those binary angles are `classes`/`structures` . Is it right?

Comment: The typedefs means that your binangs are just synonyms for the unsigned integer types. You can't protect the "new types" because there _aren't_ any new types. `binang8_t` just _is_ a `uint8_t`. Do you mean you want to force users to call a `uint8_t` a `binang8_t` if they are using your code?

Comment: `biang16_t` and `uint16_t` are the same type with different names. You can't distinguish between them in a template context if that is your question... ?

Comment: Allan Cameron I want to prevent users from mixing `uin8_t` and `binang8_t`. I want functions that take `binang8_t` as an argument to refuse to accept ` uin8_t` . 
I guess I have to give up and go with new class and explicit casts.
I hoped that `typedef` is more than just "type alias".

Comment: No it is just a type alias. In your scenario, you wouldn't be preventing users from mixing uin8_t and binang8_t, because there is nothing to mix - just identical types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enum` for just this purpose:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

enum binang8_t : uint8_t {};

template <typename T>
struct is_binang : std::false_type {};

template <>
struct is_binang<binang8_t> : std::true_type {};

// static_assert(is_binang<uint8_t>::value);  --> This fails
static_assert(is_binang<binang8_t>::value);

extern "C" void some_c_function(uint8_t);

int main() {
    binang8_t val = static_cast<binang8_t>(0);
    some_c_function(val);
    return 0;
}
```

([Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Y_XXDK))

This works because unscoped enumerations are of unique types (not the same with their underlying integer type), and they are implicitly convertible to integers (so you can pass them to C function that accepts integers without casting).

It's not perfect, I admit, as you must cast the result back to `binang8_t` if you do arithmetic operations, and it does not work for floating points.

Comment: That hack almost worked, `is_binangle` works as expected!  But now  `std::numeric_limits<A>::max()` for those new types returns `0`.

Comment: I probably can redefine `numeric_limits` in my namespace by providing 4 specializations ... its getting uglier and uglier. Why in the world the  `typedef` is not treated like a public sub-classing?

Comment: @SergeyPanov You don't have to do it in your own namespace. Go ahead and specialize the ones in the `std` namespace. It is [allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122912/is-it-ok-to-specialize-stdnumeric-limitst-for-user-defined-number-like-class) by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

It is a half answer (a template class replacing those 4 `typedef`-s) but yet another problem -- the text-book member template function implementation fails)

In hopes that I will be able to convince C coders that an array of C++

```
struct blah {
  uint16_t value;
};
```

can be treated as an array of the `uint16_t` values, I did try going the high road of declaring a `class`:

```
template<typename UnsignedInt,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<UnsignedInt>::value, int> = 0>
class binangle {
    UnsignedInt value;
public:
    binangle(UnsignedInt v) : value(v) {}

    template<typename F>
    binangle(F v) { set_from_radians<F>(v); }

    template<typename F>
    void set_from_radians(F rad);

    template<typename F>
    void set_from_degrees(F rad);

    template<typename F>
    F to_radians(int start_deg = 0) const;

    template<typename F>
    F to_degrees(int start_deg = 0) const;

    template<typename F> operator F() const;

    explicit operator UnsignedInt() const { return value; }
};
```

... it was all dandy till I started implementation of those template member functions - when compiler sees

```
template<typename UnsignedInt>
template<typename F>
void binangle<UnsignedInt>::set_from_radians(F rad) {
...
```

it throws

```
...
   /home/sipan/src/vgit/signals/tests/../include/binangles_impl.hpp:23:51: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class signals::binangle<UnsignedInt>’
   23 | void binangle<UnsignedInt>::set_from_radians(F rad) {
      |
```

Comment: dropping `, std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<UnsignedInt>::value, int> = 0` in the class declaration saved the day, but why?

Comment: I solved it by adding `static_assert(std::is_unsigned<UnsignedInt>::value)` and   `static_assert(std::is_floating_point<F>::value)` to all those functions.