# Is it permissible to specialize mathematical constants for custom numeric types?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-specialization

Suppose I create my own floating point type `MyFloatingPoint` (e.g. to provide increased precision relative to the built-in types). Is it permissible to specialize the constants in the C++20 `<numbers>` header for this type, or is this undefined behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to C++20 [draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/math.constants) it seems fine:

> 26.9.2
> (...)
> 2. Pursuant to 16.5.4.2.1, a program may partially or explicitly specialize a mathematical constant variable
> template provided that the specialization depends on a program-defined type

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but only if the specialization depends on a program-defined type (rather than only built-in / standard library types).

See [[math.constants]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/math.constants#2) in the post-C++20 draft of the C++ standard.

Note that without such a specific permission in the standard, it is generally *not* allowed to specialize a standard library variable template. See [[namespace.std]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/namespace.std#3).

Comment: The topic of specializing standard library templates is slightly more complex I'd say, see e.g.: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16519653/4885321).

Comment: @alagner Yes, in general for standard library templates it is more complex. But specifically for standard library _variable_ templates the linked paragraph generally forbids specialization without specific permission. Many of the answers/comments in the question you linked were written before variable templates existed, so they might not be taking that into account.

Answer (score -1):

No it isn't undefined behavior (be careful when to use that term).
I don't see any big issues with that (specialy not after reading the other comments).

```
#include <numbers>

struct my_floatingpoint_t
{
    double value;
};

namespace std
{
    namespace numbers
    {
        template<>
        constexpr my_floatingpoint_t pi_v<my_floatingpoint_t>{3.14};
    }
}


int main()
{
    auto pi = std::numbers::pi_v<double>;
    auto my_pi = std::numbers::pi_v<my_floatingpoint_t>;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suppose one should be careful here, since it is by default forbidden to specialize standard library variable templates. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/namespace.std#3. The `<numbers>` ones just give specific permission.

Comment: I agree, it is always advisable to put your own stuff in other namespaces then std

Comment: I think identifiers ending in _t are not allowed

Comment: @Sebastion I double checked, it is not forbidden it is a POSIX naming convention. So  you can run into naming conflicts if you use POSIX. So like any C++ program its best to define your own types in a namespace (I always do that in bigger projects, but I tend to skip it for examples).

Comment: So only reserved in Posix and not in the C++ standard itself

Comment: Yup, just found this topic. It discusses it in detail : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent/12727104#12727104 (Seems to be more related to "C" then "C++" unless I missed something)