# How to specialize std::numeric_limits for a custom templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I have my own numeric class:

```
template<class T>
class Number
{
   // Logic
};
```

and I'd like to provide values for `std::numeric_limits<MyNumber<T>>::min()` etc.

I found this answer but it's for non-template classes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38670996/1107474

and I'm struggling converting it for templated classes. I was trying:

```
namespace std 
{
    template<class T> 
    class numeric_limits<Number<T>> 
    {
    public:
        static Number<T> min()
        {
            return Number<T>(1, 0);
        };
    };
}
```

> I get:
>
> ```
> template argument 1 is invalid
>   279 |     class numeric_limits<Number<T>>
>                                          ^
> ```

Comment: Are you compiling for C++11 or later?

Comment: @NicolBolas yes

Comment: The syntax is correct. Can you provide a full [mre] demonstrating the error?

Comment: personally, I wouldn't bother with this, unless your class wss super-popular.

Comment: This seems to compile fine https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7Wo4W919q